# Show default country and state for public proximity search

Tags: search

I'm trying to figure out how I can set public-facing proximity searches in 4.7.25 to default to civiCRM's default country?

Currently, the user is required to select a country and state, but 99% of our searches happen within the same country.

is there a way to set this?

Answer (score 1):

The profile search fields respect the system-wide default country.  To set the default country:

- **Administer menu » Localization » Languages, Currency, Location**.
- *Default Country* is located about halfway down the page.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I'm running v4.7.3 on Joomla 3.8.6, and while I have Default Country selected, when I provide a public link to a profile which allows for Proximity search, the Country dropdown does not default to the Default Country.

see :
https://www.cahpi.ca/index.php?option=com_civicrm&view=Profiles&layout=search&task=civicrm/profile&gid=21&reset=1&Itemid=43&lang=en

Comment: Ah, you're correct.  The default country is respected on "create" but not on search.  You may want to file a bug report on this, but given limited resources you may need to submit a fix yourself or hire someone!  I imagine that you're not the first person to find this, but it's not worth it to fund a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across the same problem myself - for country, not for state - so I wrote an extension (com.megaphonetech.defaultcountrysearch) to automatically set the default country on profile search forms when such a field exists.  You can [download it here](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.defaultcountrysearch).  It should be reasonably easy to add support for a default state as well!